# Disable global IAuthorizationRequirement for certain pages

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Custom IAuthorizationRequirement implementation where i want to simply validate if the user is allowed for the page based on the tenant claim of the user.

```
public class TenantAccessRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

The actual tenant will be resolved in the AuthorizationHandler.
This IAuthorizationRequirement is globally applied in the Startup AddAuthorizationMethod

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireClaim(AuthorizationConstants.TenantIdClaimType)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddRequirements(new TenantAccessRequirement())
                .Build();
        });
```

Some pages are not tenant specific so i want to override the requirement, the same way Authorize / Allow Anonymous are working. How can i achieve this ? I dont want to remove the tenant access requirement from the global policy because there are just a few pages that will not be tenant specific.
The best way would be another Attribute that overwrites the TenantaccessRequirement.

One option i was thinking about was register another handler for the same requirement and check if the requirements of the context contains the anonymous tenant requirement.

```
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TenantAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Requirements.Any(r => r.GetType() == typeof(AnonymousTenantRequirement)))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
```

But this seems a bit dirty as the AnonymousTenantRequirement isn't an actual requirement.

Comment: `there are just a few pages that will not be tenant specific.` Can you clarify more about "pages" here? Does it mean specific action method, page handler etc, not affect all other endpoints?

Comment: Its currently just an access denied  and a tenant selection page . Both are implemented using razor pages. But i dont want to exclude that this requirment is possible for other types of endpoints including API for example.